# Python 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, list, int, typeerror, min

I'm in the process of writing one of my first programs and receiving an error when testing it against another program. Below is the snippet of code at the beginning of my program that's first throwing the issue:

```
def stats(list_doc):

    #Minimum
    min_val = min(list_doc)
    int(min_val)

    #Maximum
    max_val = max(list_doc)
    int(max_val)

    #Mean
    total = sum(list_doc)
    length = len(list_doc)
    for nums in [list_doc]:
        mean_val = total / length
        float(mean_val)

    #Median
    sorted(list_doc)
    med_val = sorted(lst)
    lstLen = len(lst)
    index = (lstLen - 1) // 2

    if (lstLen % 2):
        return med_val[index]
    else:
        return (med_val[index] + med_val[index + 1])/2.0

    return min_val, max_val, mean_val, med_val
```

And this is the code I'm running it against to actually perform the function against a list of numbers.

```
    list_doc = list(range(51)) # from 0 to 50. an odd number of elements.
    min_val, max_val, mean_val, med_val = stats(list_doc)
    print("Minimum = {0} is of type {1}.".format(min_val, type(min_val)))
    print("Maximum = {0} is of type {1}.".format(max_val, type(max_val)))
    print("Mean = {0:.1f} is of type {1}.".format(mean_val, type(mean_val)))
    print("Median = {0:.1f} is of type {1}.".format(med_val, type(med_val)))
```

I receive a TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable. Error text is below:

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-25-6a4f116bc5b5> in <module>()
      1 list_doc = list(range(51)) # from 0 to 50. an odd number of elements.
----> 2 min_val, max_val, mean_val, med_val = stats(list_doc)
      3 print("Minimum = {0} is of type {1}.".format(min_val, type(min_val)))
      4 print("Maximum = {0} is of type {1}.".format(max_val, type(max_val)))
      5 print("Mean = {0:.1f} is of type {1}.".format(mean_val, type(mean_val)))

    TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I thought that lists were already iterable, but I'm not quite sure what direction to go in from here.

Comment: Lists are iterable, what you think is a list must actually be an integer.

Comment: what's the output of the print statement ?

Comment: It doesn't get as far as the print statement. Code fails at min_val of line 2 of second program.

Comment: With your last edit, the code changed considerably. Could you comment, what you did? With the current version, your other code following after the first return is not reached at all.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I originally thought I would just add the parts of the code I thought would be relevant to answer my question of the typerror, but I regret doing so because there are definitely elements viewed by others that you would have no idea what they were doing there. I added the rest of my code and the full text of the code I run my program against in order to fully show what I'm doing.

Comment: Ok, but the problem is, that your coding after the first return is not reached at all. The first return leads to the error condition (as described in my answer below).

Comment: We are working on a moving target here?? Still there are return statements that lead to an error! (see your if statement)

Comment: @look__out Stackoverflow's goal is to create an archive of question and answer information for programmers.  Consequently it is bad form to repeatedly make major changes to the question   With every change, the existing answers no longer useful.  A reader might not even know why the answers are written.

Comment: @John1024 Thanks for saying that. StackOverflow has been such a resource to me so far. I'll make sure to leave code in question as is and reflect changes in comments.

Answer (score 7):

Observe the return value of `stats`:

```
In [7]: stats(list_doc)
Out[7]: 0
```

Now, look at the next statement:

```
min_val, max_val, mean_val, med_val = stats(list_doc)
```

This generates an error because you are asking for four values and supplying only one.

If you intend that `stats` should return four values, then it needs to be modified.

#### Suggested Code for `stats` Function

Consider:

```
def stats(x):
     return min(x), max(x), sum(x)/len(x), sorted(x)[len(x)//2]
```

#### Discussion of Code in Revised Question

Consider:

```
def stats(list_doc):

    #Minimum
    min_val = min(list_doc)
    int(min_val)
    return min_val

    #Maximum
    max_val = max(list_doc)
    int(max_val)
    return max_val

    #Mean
    total = sum(list_doc)
    length = len(list_doc)
    for nums in [list_doc]:
        mean_val = total / length
        float(mean_val)
        return mean_val

    #Median
    sorted(list_doc)
    med_val = sorted(lst)
    lstLen = len(lst)
    index = (lstLen - 1) // 2

    if (lstLen % 2):
        return med_val[index]
    else:
        return (med_val[index] + med_val[index + 1])/2.0

    return min_val, max_val, mean_val, med_val
```

When a python function encounters a `return` statement, it returns.  Thus, after computing the minimum, the following statement is executed:

```
    return min_val
```

With that statement, the function execution stops.  None of the statements which follow it are executed.

Separately, consider this statement:

```
int(min_val)
```

This function takes the value of `min_val` and returns it as  an integer.  The return of value of the function is not assigned to anything.  Therefore, it is ignored.  The value of `min_val` is unchanged.  Maybe, the intent is:

```
min_val = int(min_val)
```

Also, consider the line:

```
sorted(list_doc)
```

This line returns a sorted list but the return value is ignored.  `list_doc` remains unchanged.  If you want to change `list_doc` in place, use:

```
list_doc.sort()
```

Comment: Apologies - I have added my full code to the body of the question.

Comment: @look__out OK.  See updated answer for a discussion of how python treats return statements.

Comment: Very helpful! I have removed the returns from the min, max, mean functions. Left them at the last median function as I'm figuring out how to make sure my if statement still works. As of right now, code is still getting hung up on the 'int' object not iterable and stopping at the min_val position of line 2 of second piece of code.

Comment: @look__out Have you considered my suggested 2-line replacement for the `stats` function?

Comment: That solved the issues for me - replacing my functions with your your suggestion. A much simpler, cleaner solution than what I had originally. Still going to work at my implementation a bit, but it's helpful to have a piece of working code to help me along. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Your `stats()` function isn't return everything you want. You probably meant to do something like

```
def stats(list_doc):

    #Minimum
    min_val = min(list_doc)
    max_val = ...
    mean_val = ...
    med_val = ...
    return min_val, max_val, mean_val, med_val
```

Comment: I have now added my full code to the body of the question - sorry about that.

Comment: It still doesn't look right. The function will return `min_val` and not execute the rest of the code. OK, after your last edit, your code will still not get to `return min_val, max_val, mean_val, med_val` because you are return in the `if ... else...` statement right above it.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is in this line:

```
min_val, max_val, mean_val, med_val = stats(list_doc)
```

You only return one value at the moment, but are attempting to split it between four variables.

So,

```
min_val, max_val, mean_val, med_val = 0
```

fails because 0 isn't iterable and thus can't be split between the four variables. HOWEVER, something like:

```
min_val, max_val, mean_val, med_val = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

would work because the list (an **iterable**), can populate each of your values:

```
min_val = 1
max_val = 2
mean_val = 3
med_val = 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second line

```
int(min_val)
```

Does currently nothing, since the result is not assigned to any variable.

The return value min_val is an integer and your assignment

```
min_val, max_val, mean_val, med_val = stats(list_doc)
```

does not work at all. Since your function returns an integer and not multiple values.

When you want to assign to multiple values, you normally have to return a list or tuple of values -- but you return just one value. Since Python also accepts any iterable (lists and tuples are iterable), the message says, that int is not iterable.

Answer (score 1):

Your returns are not doing what you think. Once the code hits a return it exits the function. You're not returing all those values you are only returning the first one, `min_val`.

Whatever value is in `min_val` can't be iterated over to assign values in the the assigment:

```
min_val, max_val, mean_val, med_val = stats(list_doc)
```

which using an arbitrary value for `min_val` would look like this:

```
min_val, max_val, mean_val, med_val = 4
```

Which is not valid. You need to remove all but one of the returns and change that one to:

```
return min_val, max_val, mean_val, med_val
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I have removed the returns from all but my median statement right now. Trying to get rid of those so the final return line in the primary code does what it's supposed to.